# How to update Multiple radio button value into database using id

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have listed my table(leaveform) records(50) using datatable API. In my table I have a column to approve leave. This column consist of two radio buttons(Approve and Reject). Each record have its own unique id. Now I want to update the values into database using those unique id.

This is my Table
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create one function and that function is called by clicking on 'Approve' or 'Reject'. Let me give you example.

For e.g. : you have two radio button as below.
Approve and Reject

Now, You have to create one function that will be called by clicking on radio button. as explained below.

```
<input type="radio" name="rndLeave" value="approve" onclick="changeLeaveStatus(leaveid, 'approve')" /> Approve

<input type="radio" name="rndLeave" value="reject" onclick="changeLeaveStatus(leaveid, 'reject')" /> Reject
```

// first argument is leave id

// second argument is leave status.

```
function changeLeaveStatus(leaveid, leaveStatus)
{

      $.ajax({
           url: 'leave_status.php',
           data: 'id='+leaveid+'&status='+leaveStatus,
           type: 'POST',
           success: function() {
           },
           error: function(){
           }
      });

}
```

This way you can update leave status from jquery datatable.

Comment: note : that you can create only one jquery listener on the table, instead of repeating onclick="..." on every row. for infos here is the link : http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

you should use jquery onclick on table with handler "tr" -> send ajax data to update.

```
$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "change", "input[type=radio]", function() {
  console.log( $( this ).text() );

   $.get( "path_to_php_page/update.php?id="+$( this ).attr("id")+"&state="+$(this).children("input[type=radio]:checked").val(), function( data ) {
      console.log( data );
   });
});
```

in update.php
you should get the id of the row with `$_GET['id']` and the state with `$_GET['state']`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but i want to update the database when i click the update button..

Comment: this code will call update.php when you click on button radio.  no ?

Comment: You should [quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I see your tag has jquery so I guess you may want jquery code for solve this problem. here it is.

```
$( "#button_update" ).click( function() { //on click button update
    var approve = new Array();
    for (i=1;i<=count;i++) {
       if ($('#id' + i).attr('checked') == 'checked'){
          approve[i-1] = $('#id' + i).attr('id');
       }
    }

    $.post(url, 
         { approve: approve },
         function(data) {

         });
});
```